# Encryption Program Not Working

Tags: python, encryption, ascii

**Here is my code so far** 
basically what I need to do is create a encryption and decryption based program that can open and encode / decode files then save the decrypted / encrypted message. As you can see I have used a keyword Caesar cipher that will shift the message along. However, I am relatively new to python and have little knowledge of how I will save the encoded or decoded message or how to open a message to encode / decode. Help would really be appreciated.

```
def getMode():
    while True:
        print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?')
        mode = input().lower()
        if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():
            return mode
        else:
            print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')
def getMessage():
    file=input("enter file name (dont write .txt)")
    f = open (file+'.txt','r')
    return input()
def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True:
        print('Enter the key number (1-%s)' % 26)
        key = int(input())
        if (key >= 1 and key <= 26):
            return key
def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key):
    if mode[0] == 'd':
        key = -key
    translated = ''
    for symbol in message:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key
            if symbol.isupper():
                if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('A'):
                    num += 26
            elif symbol.islower():
                if num > ord('z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('a'):
                    num += 26
            translated += chr(num)
        else:
            translated += symbol
    return translated
mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
key = getKey()
print('Your translated text is:')
print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
getMode()
getMessage()
getKey()
getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key)
getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should review the getMessage() function.  It's not actually returning the contents of the file.

Changing getMessage() as follows made it work.

```
def getMessage():
    file=input("enter file name (dont write .txt)")
    with open(file+'.txt', 'r') as text_file:
      read_data = text_file.read()
    return read_data
```

Comment: It really is better to use variables that have a meaning than something like  `f`. We, as developers, write code for the next developer to read and understand easily and quickly. Later in the code if is less clear what `f` is. Yes, we have to type more and we do have autocompletion in many IDEs to help with that.

Comment: Yes... agreed. I will edit the answer.